# Displaying environment variables in assembly language

Tags: parsing, gcc, assembly, x86-64

I am trying to understand how assembly works by making a basic program to display environement variables like

C code :

```
    int         main(int ac, char **av, char **env)
    {
     int        x;
     int        y;

     y = -1;
     while (env[++y])
       {
        x = -1;
        while (env[y][++x])
          {
           write(1, &(env[y][x]), 1);
          }
       }
     return (0);
    }
```

I compiled that with gcc -S (on cygwin64) to see how to do, and wrote it my own way (similar but not same), but it did not work...

```
    $>gcc my_av.s && ./a.exe

    HOMEPATH=\Users\hadrien▒2▒p
```

My assembly code :

```
        .file   "test.c"
    .LC0:
        .ascii "\n\0"
    .LC1:
        .ascii "\033[1;31m.\033[0m\0"   
    .LC2:
        .ascii "\033[1;31m#\033[0m\0"
    .LCtest0:
        .ascii "\033[1;32mdebug\033[0m\0"
    .LCtest1:
        .ascii "\033[1;31mdebug\033[0m\0"
    .LCtest2:
        .ascii "\033[1;34mdebug\033[0m\0"

        .def    main;   .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    main:
        /* initialisation du main */
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        subq    $48, %rsp
        movl    %ecx, 16(%rbp) /* int argc */
        movq    %rdx, 24(%rbp) /* char **argv */
        movq    %r8, 32(%rbp) /* char **env */

        /* saut de ligne */
        /* write init */
        movl    $1, %r8d /* write size */
        movl    $1, %ecx /* sortie standart */
        leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rdx
        /* write */
        call    write

        /* debut du code */
        movl    $-1, -8(%rbp) /* y = -1 */
        jmp .Loop_1_condition

    .Loop_1_body:
        movl    $-1, -4(%rbp)
        jmp .Loop_2_condition

    .Loop_2_body:
        /* affiche le charactere */
        movl    $1, %r8d
        movl    $1, %ecx
        call    write

    .Loop_2_condition:
        addl    $1, -4(%rbp) /* x = -1 */
        movl    -8(%rbp), %eax
        cltq
        addq    32(%rbp), %rax
        movq    (%rax), %rax
        movq    %rax, %rdx
        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
        cltq
        addq    %rdx, %rax
        movq    %rax, %rdx
        movq    (%rax), %rax
        cmpq    $0, %rax
        jne .Loop_2_body

        /* saut de ligne */
        movl    $1, %r8d /* write size */
        movl    $1, %ecx /* sortie standart */
        leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rdx
        call    write

    .Loop_1_condition:
        addl    $1, -8(%rbp) /* ++y */
        movl    -8(%rbp), %eax
        cltq /* passe eax en 64bits */
        addq    32(%rbp), %rax
        movq    (%rax), %rax
        cmpq    $0, %rax
        jne .Loop_1_body

        movl    $1, %r8d /* write size */
        movl    $1, %ecx /* sortie standart */
        leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rdx
        call    write

        /* fin du programme */
        movl    $0, %eax /* return (0) */
        addq    $48, %rsp
        popq    %rbp
        ret
        .def    write;  .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
```

Could someone explain me what is wrong with this code please ?

Also, while trying to solve the problem i tired to replace $0 by $97 in cmpq operation, thinking it would stop on 'a' character but it didn't... Why ?

Comment: They way you use `y` to offset `env` in your assembly code doesn't look right. A `char*` is larger than one byte.

Comment: Also, the environment is different when you assemble with as or gcc. Gcc adds "C-interface" to the program prologue.

Comment: See https://www.dropbox.com/s/pdcvw8q9ypxtapg/filexor.s.txt?dl=0

Comment: Michael > yep you are right... even with à simple loop env [y], I don't get the good variables number...       turboscrew > yeah, gcc wont let me compile unless I have main label, I'm going to have a look to your link thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues. In this code (loop2) you have:

```
    addq    %rdx, %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdx
    movq    (%rax), %rax
    cmpq    $0, %rax
```

`movq (%rax), %rax` has read the next 8 characters in *%rax*. You are only interested in the first character. One way to achieve this is to compare the least significant byte in *%rax* with 0. You can use *cmpb* and use the %al register:

```
    cmpb    $0, %al
```

The biggest issue though is understanding that `char **env` is a pointer to array of `char *` .You first need to get the base pointer for the array, then that base pointer is indexed with `y`. The indexing looks something like basepointer + (y * 8) . You need to multiply `y` by 8 because each pointer is 8 bytes wide. The pointer at that location will be the `char *` for a particular environment string. Then you can index each character in the string array until you find a *NUL* (0) terminating character.

I've amended the code slightly and added comments on the few lines I changed:

```
    .file   "test.c"
.LC0:
    .ascii "\x0a\0"
.LC1:
    .ascii "\033[1;31m.\033[0m\0"
.LC2:
    .ascii "\033[1;31m#\033[0m\0"
.LCtest0:
    .ascii "\033[1;32mdebug\033[0m\0"
.LCtest1:
    .ascii "\033[1;31mdebug\033[0m\0"
.LCtest2:
    .ascii "\033[1;34mdebug\033[0m\0"

    .def    main;   .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
main:
    /* initialisation du main */
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    subq    $48, %rsp
    movl    %ecx, 16(%rbp) /* int argc */
    movq    %rdx, 24(%rbp) /* char **argv */
    movq    %r8, 32(%rbp) /* char **env */

    /* saut de ligne */
    /* write init */
    movl    $1, %r8d /* write size */
    movl    $1, %ecx /* sortie standart */
    leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rdx
    /* write */
    call    write

    /* debut du code */
    movl    $-1, -8(%rbp) /* y = -1 */
    jmp .Loop_1_condition

.Loop_1_body:
    movl    $-1, -4(%rbp)
    jmp .Loop_2_condition

.Loop_2_body:
    /* affiche le charactere */
    movl    $1, %r8d
    movl    $1, %ecx
    call    write

.Loop_2_condition:
    addl    $1, -4(%rbp) /* x = -1 */
    movl    -8(%rbp), %eax        /* get y index */
    cltq
    movq    32(%rbp), %rbx        /* get envp (pointer to element 0 of char * array) */
    movq    (%rbx,%rax,8), %rdx   /* get pointer at envp+y*8
                                     pointers are 8 bytes wide */

    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax        /* get x */
    cltq
    leaq    (%rdx, %rax), %rdx    /* Get current character's address */
    cmpb    $0, (%rdx)            /* Compare current byte to char 0
                                     using cmpq will compare the next 8 bytes */
    jne .Loop_2_body

    /* saut de ligne */
    movl    $1, %r8d /* write size */
    movl    $1, %ecx /* sortie standart */
    leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rdx
    call    write

.Loop_1_condition:
    addl    $1, -8(%rbp) /* ++y */
    movl    -8(%rbp), %eax
    cltq /* passe eax en 64bits */
    movq    32(%rbp), %rbx        /* get envp (pointer to element 0 of char * array) */
    movq    (%rbx,%rax,8), %rax   /* get pointer at envp+y*8
                                     pointers are 8 bytes wide */
    cmpq    $0, %rax              /* Compare to NULL ptr */
    jne .Loop_1_body

    movl    $1, %r8d /* write size */
    movl    $1, %ecx /* sortie standart */
    leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rdx
    call    write

    /* fin du programme */
    movl    $0, %eax /* return (0) */
    addq    $48, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    ret
    .def    write;  .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
```

Comment: Thank you VERY much ! Thanks for having taken the time to correct my code !

You solved the problem, and explained what were wrong and why... perfect ! love you <3

Know I understand why gcc -S was doing something like : leaq    0(,%rax,8), %rdx, It is similar to your : movq    (%rbx,%rax,8), %rax, right ?

Comment: If I was parsing an int array instead of char array, I would change this : leaq (%rdx, %rax), %rdx, to : leaq (%rdx, %rax, 4), %rdx ?

Comment: @Hadrien : One other observation. It appears you noticed the `cltq` instruction. This sign extends (_EAX_) into the full 64-bit _RAX_ register. This was done because you declared _x_ and _y_ as signed integers. Had you made them unsigned the the code generated would have not needed the `cltq` . Since the array indexes in this case will always be positive you could avoid using `cltq`. When you `mov` a value into a 32 bit register(_EAX_ for example), by default the upper 32 bits of the 64-bit register (_RAX_) will be automatically zeroed out.

Comment: Thank you for this details ! But it's not perfectly clear in my mind. I'm going to look for more documentation to understand how memory works and in what order bits follow each others. However, thank you for your help and for your time !